# Count how many times values has appeared in list so far

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of non-unique values. I want to output a list of the same length where each value corresponds to how many times that value has appeared so far.

The code I have written to do this seems over-complicated, so I think there has to be a better way.

```
x = [1,1,2,3,1,3]


def times_so_far(ls):

    out = [0]*len(x)
    counted = {}
    for i,v in enumerate(x):
        if v in counted:
            counted[v] += 1
        else:
            counted[v] = 0

        out[i] = counted[v]
    return out

times_so_far(x)
#[0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1]
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: What you wrote is actually pretty good, certainly better than the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe using list.count() you can achieve the same with less lines?

```
x = [1,1,2,3,1,3]

def times_so_far(ls):

    out = [0]*len(ls)
    for i in xrange(len(ls)):
        out[i] = ls[:i].count(ls[i]) 
    return out
```

This can be written with list comprehension as mentioned by Caridorc, and it removes the first `len(ls)` call this way (though maybe at the cost of resizing `out` for every element of the list):

```
def times_so_far(ls):

    return [ls[:i].count(ls[i]) for i in xrange(len(ls))]
```

Now, if you're going to work with lists of positive integers of a small value, I would recommend the following, as it's similar to yours but it works with indices instead of dict keys:

```
def times_so_far(ls, maxValue):
   temp = [0]*(maxValue+1)
   out = [0]*len(ls)
   for i in xrange(len(ls)):
      out[i] = temp[ls[i]]
      temp[ls[i]] += 1
   return out
```

Comment: Yes, list.count seems much better. I think I'll use this (I think it's `ls[i]` and not `ls[i+1]`, though)

Comment: Yes, sorry, I noticed the same, it's already fixed.

Comment: Isn't this slower, and also have the same worst case memory usage?

Comment: @JoeWallis It's Python... probably the slowest language out there. If performance is a problem then I would suggest moving on to another language.

Comment: My point is your _algorithm_'s speed is \$O(n^2)\$ where OP's was \$O(n)\$.
And you also use \$O(3n)\$ memory.
IMO that's a bad thing to say is a good algorithm. In any language.

Comment: @JoeWallis now that you mention it, I don't think it's the worst case memory usage, unless python performs a poor management of the memory of its lists. I believe `xrange` is more "memory efficient" and "faster" than  `enumerate` , and depending on how lists are internally constructed, the `ls[:i]` may not really take that much memory or perform allocations, but I don't know because I never analyzed the underlying C code for that. A proper manager would reuse the list discarded in the previous iteration, or it could simply reference the original list and override the begin and end indices.

Comment: @JoeWallis  Remember that `counted[v]` has to perform a search to look for v (it's not an access by index but by key). The original verison also contains branches while mine doesn't. I don't think the language "doesn't matter" either, in particular if you care about performance.

Comment: @hackerman `out` and `ls` is 2n. `ls[:i]` is a copy which is why `i[:]` is good. And so \$O(3n)\$. And `dict` lookup is \$O(1)\$. Since this is tagged _algorithm_ I would assume they want it improved...

Comment: I thought that by "better way" she meant "less complicated", as in "less lines of code". Also, if `ls[:i]` is a copy, it's because of a poor implementation, as it could be just a reference to the original if none of the lists are modifying the values nor shrinking it's underlying memory array.

Comment: Notice that the fact that `ls[:i]` is a copy is just because it's Python. In C you would simply increment a counter that would tell where `count()` should stop, so the `copy` is not something relevant to the algorithm itself, but to the language chosen to express it. Maybe `count()` should accept a second parameter taking a stop offset.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), to remove the `if v else`.
To achieve this, you can do:

```
from collections import defaultdict
counted = defaultdict(int)
for i,v in enumerate(x):
    counted[v] += 1
```

To remove the need for `out` and `enumerate` you can `yield` on each iteration.
This would make your code very small and readable.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def times_so_far(list_):
    counted = defaultdict(int)
    for v in list_:
        counted[v] += 1
        yield counted[v]

print(list(times_so_far([1,1,2,3,1,3])))
#[0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1]
```

It will return a [generator object](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), hence why I use `list`.
If this is a problem then you can change `yield` to `out.append()` and re-add out.

This has \$O(n)\$ runtime, with a min \$O(n)\$ and maximum \$O(2n)\$ memory usage.

Answer (score 4):

I propose a very slow solution, \$O(N^2)\$ in time and space.

The benefits of this solution are its clarity and simplicity.

Knowing that:

- `xs[:i]` gives all the elements of `xs` up to the index `i`
- `enumerate` yields an `index, value` pair,

The following is easier to understand than English:

```
def times_so_far(xs):
    return [xs[:index].count(x) for index, x in enumerate(xs)]
```

In case you care about performance, you may prefer using a `Counter` or a `defaultdict` as suggested by @Joe Wallis and @Ethan Bierlein

Answer (score 4):

I would use the "high-performance" (as described in documentation) `Counter` class for this task. You can actually get a complete counter at every step, but that is of course more than you asked for.

This is my implementation:

```
from collections import Counter

def times_so_far(nums):
    return list(times_so_far_generator(nums))

def times_so_far_generator(nums):
    counter = Counter()
    for num in nums:
        counter[num] += 1
        yield counter[num]
```

I like this solution because:

- It is fast: uses generators + `Counter` and asymptotically optimal \$O(n)\$ performance with respect to both memory and time.
- It is very readable and understandable
- It generalizes (`yield counter` instead of `yield counter[num]` to get a full `Counter` at every position). You can also return a tuple of the counts with the element with `yield (num, counter[num])`
- It uses the specifically designed `Counter` instead of a generic `defaultdict`, and so is more fitting to the task (and can possibly perform better, as values are integers instead of any object)
- It works on arbitrary iterables (even infinitely long ones, if you use the generator version)

Comment: Whoever down voted...please explain yourselves?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but calling `Counter` "high-performance" may be something of a misnomer. The only high-performance aspects of it relative to an ordinary dict or a defaultdict are creating or `update`-ing it from an input iterable, and even then, only on Python 3.3 and up. Other than that, it's either equivalent in speed or slower than dict or defaultdict.

Comment: @user2357112 I was simply referring to the way it is described in the official documentation. The collections module is described as "High-performance container datatypes"

Comment: I timed both `Counter` and `defaultdict` in [Python2](http://ideone.com/D7z9Ob) and [Python3](http://ideone.com/iwMENk). (It's only one data set so it may be significantly different on a larger data set.)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest a vectorized approach making heavy usage of NumPy functions which might be beneficial as we are focusing on performance here. The steps to solve our case could be put together as shown below -

```
# Get counts for each label in input array
counts = np.bincount(X)

# Setup ID array that will ultimately when cumulatively summed would give us 
# such a ramp-like array corresponding to an otherwise sorted input array 
id_arr = np.ones(len(X),dtype=int)
id_arr[0] = 0
id_arr[counts[:-1].cumsum()] = -counts[:-1]+1    

# Perform cumlative summation and go back to original order using double argsorting
out = id_arr.cumsum()[np.argsort(X,kind='mergesort').argsort()]
```

Please note that the input expected would be a NumPy array.

**Benchmarking**

Let's test out all the approaches posted thus far to solve the problem. I have compiled all the solutions as functions with names attributed to their respective author names. Listed below are the compiled codes -

```
def times_so_far_hackerman(ls):
    out = [0]*len(ls)
    for i in xrange(len(ls)):
        out[i] = ls[:i].count(ls[i]) 
    return out

def times_so_far_JoeWallis(list_):
    counted = defaultdict(int)
    for v in list_:
        counted[v] += 1
        yield counted[v]-1

def times_so_far_generator(nums):
    counter = Counter()
    for num in nums:
        counter[num] += 1
        yield counter[num]-1

def times_so_far_mleyfman(nums):
    return list(times_so_far_generator(nums))

def times_so_far_Caridorc(xs):
    return [xs[:index].count(x) for index, x in enumerate(xs)]

def times_so_far_vectorized(X):
    counts = np.bincount(X)
    id_arr = np.ones(len(X),dtype=int)
    id_arr[0] = 0
    id_arr[counts[:-1].cumsum()] = -counts[:-1]+1    
    return id_arr.cumsum()[np.argsort(X,kind='mergesort').argsort()]
```

Now, let's start timings these. Let's start with a relatively decent sized list of numbers :

```
In [9]: %timeit times_so_far(x)
   ...: %timeit times_so_far_hackerman(x)
   ...: %timeit list(times_so_far_JoeWallis(x))
   ...: %timeit times_so_far_mleyfman(x)
   ...: %timeit times_so_far_Caridorc(x)
   ...: %timeit times_so_far_vectorized(np.array(x))
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 3.27 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 1.3 s per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.03 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 8.32 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 1.36 s per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.44 ms per loop
```

So, the three fastest approaches are :

```
times_so_far()
times_so_far_JoeWallis()
times_so_far_vectorized()
```

Let's use a bigger sized array to test out those three :

```
In [10]: # Input array with random elements between 0 amnd 100
    ...: x = np.random.randint(0,500,(50000)).tolist()

In [11]: %timeit times_so_far(x)
    ...: %timeit list(times_so_far_JoeWallis(x))
    ...: %timeit times_so_far_vectorized(np.array(x))
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 19.7 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 17.7 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 15.6 ms per loop
```

Now, if the input is already a NumPy array, `times_so_far_vectorized` can shave off the runtime spent on converting from a list to an array. Let's test out how that works out :

```
In [12]: %timeit times_so_far(x)
    ...: %timeit list(times_so_far_JoeWallis(x))
    ...: X = np.array(x)
    ...: %timeit times_so_far_vectorized(X)
    ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 19.5 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 17.6 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 11.3 ms per loop
```

So, there's a pretty good performance boost for `times_so_far_vectorized` over the other approaches!

Answer (score 2):

You're right - there is a better way. Python `list`s have a default built-in function named `count`. For example, if I wanted to count the number of times the string `"lol"` occurred in a list, I could just do this:

```
my_list = [1, 2, "lol", 3, 4, "lol", 5, 6, 7, 8, "lol"]
print(my_list.count("lol"))
```

This is ultimately better than generating a list of counts corresponding to each value as well, since it's less memory-intensive and *much* easier to work with.

In addition, if you want to take advantage of the powerful `collections` module, you should add this to the top of your code:

```
from collections import Counter
```

Then you can use the `Counter` object like this:

```
>>> print(Counter([1, 2, "lol", 3, 4, "lol", 5, 6, 7, 8, "lol"]))
Counter({'lol': 3, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1})
```

Hope this helps! :)